# Using variables globally throughout all files set up in a header file

Tags: c++, organization

Hey everyone!
I've recently started using header files in my c++ programs (fairly new to it) and was wondering what the best way to initialize global variables across all your files.

I currently have a header file outlining a program class with: init(), render(), loop(), event()... (etc)
Each of these is set up within their own own file, init.cpp etc..
So whats the best way to initialize variables so that all of the files can use them? Should I do it in the header file? Or is that a bad way to go about it.

Thanks in advance!

-Devan

Edit with organization info, didn't want to do it in the comments because there are no code blocks.

Here is my header file (CGame.h)

```
class CGame
{
public:  
    CGame();  
    int execute();
    bool init();
    void event();
    void loop();
    void render();
    void cleanUp();
protected:

private:
bool running;

}
```

And then each of those methods is defined within their own .cpp file

```
#include "CGame.h"
void CGame::render() 
{
}
```

Then all of them are called upon within my main.cpp

```
CGame::CGame()
{
    running = true;
}

int CGame::execute()
{
    if(init() == false)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while(running)
    {
        loop();
        render();
    }
        cleanUp();
        return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    CGame app;
    return app.execute();
}
```

Is this not the correct way to do it? I think I read it in an old SDL tutorial.

Comment: Maybe I'm just reading your post wrong, but it sounds like you're defining each method of your class in a separate file, which is not the way to go. Can you post a more detailed outline of how your project is organized?

Comment: @suszterpatt I edited the post with an outline. Yeah you were right about the way I was trying to do it.

Comment: Nothing prohibits defining each method in it's own cpp file. Sometimes it is even useful to split a class across multiple files (e.g. when part of the class definition is automatically generated by a GUI builder). Normally, however, it is highly unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use global variables.

Until you have learned to do without global variables, declare the variables as extern in the header file, e.g `extern int pi`. This tells the compiler: "An integer named `pi` exists, don't care where it is, the linker will know where to find it". That way you can initialize them anywhere you want.

The best location is a matter of personal taste. Basically either use a central c++-file for all the variables or put them into the c++-file that they most closely relate to. Especially if the variable is used in only one source file, do not put it in the header but declare and define it in that source file.

Comment: Thanks, ill check out extern. But does that mean if I initialize it anywhere I can use it in all the files included in the header file as well?

Comment: @pwnmonkey: Yes. That is the purpose of header files. If you use it in one source file only, declare and define it in that source file instead of in a header.

Comment: @pwnmonkey yes. If you don't want to include the entire header you could just declare `extern int AnInt` and as long as some other file has `int AnInt` it will work.

Comment: @pwnmonkey: Wait. You said `... use it in all the files included in the header file`. The header file usually includes other headers at the top. Only then does it declare it's stuff. It does usually not include other files after that. Did you mean "... use it in all the files that include that header"?

Comment: yes, sorry about my lack of detail =) and thanks for the answer!